# what onscreen keyboard is this? trying to disable

Tags: onscreen-keyboard

I accidentally enabled this annoying keyboard and I'm desperately trying to uninstall or disbale it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Yes, it is not `onboard`.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you give a `ps aux` output we can easily sort it out, but I think you can do it too.

Comment: Thanks for the `ps aux`. it was a custom test version of caribou that was running

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, well I went to "system settings" -> "keyboard" -> "shortcuts" and clicked on "Universal Access".

there you will see a bunch of options including "Turn on-screen keyboard on or off"

See if it helps.

Comment: thanks. tried this but it brings up another kind of keyboard on top of the one shown above. Not what I was looking for

Comment: Hmmmm well like kenn said there's another way just log off and then there are a bunch of settings up top again and there should be one setting which will remove it. If that doesn't work then I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "caribou", you can disable it from startup or just remove it.